# Circumferential angle in a circle, trigonometry

Tags: trigonometry

What is the length of the tendon in a circle with a radius of 10 cm if the  circumferential angle that belongs to the tendon is 77 degrees? 
[image: inscribed_angle]

Comment: I am not familiar with the term tendon in this context.  Are you trying to find the length of the arc opposite the $77^\circ$ angle?

Comment: Yes, I'm just used to saying tendon.

Comment: Do you know the central angle theorem? http://www.mathopenref.com/arccentralangletheorem.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Inscribed Angle Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inscribed_angle#Theorem) states that the measure of an inscribed angle of a circle is half the measure of the central angle that subtends the same arc of the circle.  Thus, the measure of the central angle that subtends the same arc has measure $2 \cdot 77^\circ = 154^\circ$.

The length of the arc is therefore
$$\frac{154^\circ}{360^\circ} \cdot 2\pi r$$